# Unknown html tag type

Tags: html

Looking at some old applications, the jsp pages is build with tag as such

```
<html:form action="action1">
    <html:hidden property="prop1" name="form1" value="val1" />
    <html:hidden property="prop2" name="form1" value="val2" />

    <html:text property="prop3" name="form1" />
</html>
```

Googling around, I was unable to see any similar type of tags. Can someone confirm if the above code is same as below:

```
<html>
    <form name="form1" action="action1">
        <input type="hidden" name="prop1" value="val1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="prop2" value="val2" />
        <input type="text" name="prop3"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is XML or XHTML where the namespace is declared as `html`. It should be part of a larger amount of markup where the namespace is declared and a prologue. It is not the same thing as your second form which is, I assume, your HTML interpretation of that.

Typically the first form you show would be interpreted into HTML or XHTML using XSLT or other program. The `<input>` tags need not have a closing slash in HTML.

[XML Namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have never thought of that as a namespace. Found out that it was actually one of struts namespace.